# login from webservice using web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Hi i am new person in asp.net webservice. I want to give user name and password in my web application the authentication performed by comparing username and password from webservice instead of comparing to database. Can anyone able to help me it will really appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Are we talking WCF or ASMX here? What .net version etc?

Comment: Web services are used for cross domain/platform data retrieval. I am not sure of your question, if you want to authenticate user to access the web service or you want to authenticate the user to access the web application through a web service.

Comment: @suryakiran : I developing only web application alone . My friend developing the web service . He created the database through webservice and I need to override the login authentication that he created in the web service. How can I do this?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs) - on click of login button on Login Form, you need to validate user supplied credentials by making the web service call. In case the credentials are correct then you can use [FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage.aspx) to indicate authentication success to ASP.NET runtime.

Yet another variation (along with Forms Authentication) will be to use custom membership provider. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx) to understand how membership works. Then you have to [write a custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) that will use the web service to validate user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing the webservice or it is done by someone else.

What is the functionality that you would be doing in Webservice.

I think you are trying to compare the username and password submitted with the 
values stored in the database through webservie isn't it?

If you want to compare only in webservie or any page without using the database then I think you have to hard code the useername and password and simply do string comparison.

Comment: I developing only web application alone . My friend developing the web service . He created the database through webservice and I need to override the login authentication that he created in the web service. How can I do this?Thank you